# CarouselView Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, out-of-memory, carousel

I am currently using a xamarin form version of Carousel View with ItemTemplate which have a list of templates e.g.

```
public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    private DataTemplate[] dataTemplates;

    public TemplateSelector()
    {
        dataTemplates = new DataTemplate[] {
            new DataTemplate (typeof (View1)),
            new DataTemplate (typeof (View2)),
            new DataTemplate (typeof (View3)),
            new DataTemplate (typeof (View4)),
            new DataTemplate (typeof (View5)),
            new DataTemplate (typeof (View6)),
            new DataTemplate (typeof (View7)),
            new DataTemplate (typeof (View8)),
            new DataTemplate (typeof (View9)) 
        };
    }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        var page = (WaveOobePage.Page)item;
        return dataTemplates[page.Index];
    }
```

Inside those views will include Xamarin Image control. The images file size roughly around 10kbytes.

What can I do to prevent from out of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store all the images in the memory. You must have set the image source for your all image controls.It will show out of memory exception.

Create image cache for your image controls.

For example:

you can store your image in the file and memory cache u set,

We can defined the memory cache as

```
List<Bitmap> bitmapList;
```

set the bitmapList can store 4 images

when you move to the single CarouselPage just set the image source to your image control from the "bitmapList".

If you not find the image, get the image file from your file store cache and remove the useless image from the "bitmapList" keep the size is 4

If you use the same layout for the CarouselPage, don't need to create so many views（view1， view2，view3.....） please reuse these view.

Comment: Nice theory.. I solved using FFImageLoading. I think it use similar idea as yours thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open AndroidManifest.xml file located in Properties folder of Android Project.

Add `android:largeHeap="true"` in application tag. It will solve OOM issue.

Eg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Sample.Sample" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <application android:label="Sample" android:largeHeap="true">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks but i end up using FFImageLoading and it solve the problem

Comment: What feature of FFImageLoading solved the out of memory issue because I am using it and still getting OutOfMemory issues with images in a CarouselPage