# Xamarin.Forms ListView Memory Leak

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, windows-store-apps, xamarin.forms

I am developing an enterprise application using xamarin.forms. It has been few days ListView's Memory leak issue become a nightmare for me. For the sake of simplicity I'll try to explain with sample code.
**XAML Page Code** - Page with ListView and two Button(Add & Remove)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewTest"
             x:Class="ListViewTest.MainPage">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White" x:Name ="ItemsListView">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
          <TextCell TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding ItemText}" 
                    DetailColor="Black" Detail="{Binding ItemDetail}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Add" Clicked="AddItemClicked"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="Remove" Clicked="RemoveItemClicked"/>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**C# Code Behind** - Just adding and removing objects from collection.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<SampleData> itemsListCollection;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            itemsListCollection = new ObservableCollection<SampleData>();
            ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemsListCollection;
        }
        void AddItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SampleData data = new SampleData();
            data.ItemText = "An Item";
            data.ItemDetail = "Item - " + (itemsListCollection.Count + 1).ToString();
            itemsListCollection.Add(data);
        }

        void RemoveItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SampleData item = (SampleData)ItemsListView.SelectedItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                itemsListCollection.Remove(item);
            }
        }

    }
```

**Data class** - Just two properties

```
class SampleData
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
        private string itemText;
        public string ItemText
        {
            get
            {
                return itemText;
            }
            set
            {
                itemText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemText");
            }
        }
        private string itemDetail;
        public string ItemDetail
        {
            get
            {
                return itemDetail;
            }
            set
            {
                itemDetail = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemDetail");
            }
        }
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Add Button - Adds item to ListView 
Remove Button - Removes item from ListView

**Problem** -

1. Add some items to list.
2. Remove few or all.
3. All previously added **SampleData** objects remain in memory even after all the items have
   been removed using Remove button.

[Image - Memory Snapshot of original application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60oRa.png)

[Image - Detailed Memory Snapshot of sample application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbcdr.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a PropertyChanged event handler still referencing your SampleData objects? This will prevent them from being garbage collected.

Comment: PropertyChanged event handler could be one of the possible case but the same code written for WPF application does not leaks memory. I have added more images for your reference. Actually in the project i have used MVVM light. Here i used Property Changed event handler just for example.

Comment: just updated the images... please help me. I can provide you more information if needed

Comment: Can you try to define to implement interface in "class SampleData:INotifyPropertyChanged"

Comment: what tool do you use to get snaphosts of memory?

Comment: @YuriS VS 2015 Diagnostic tool

Comment: @YuriS implementing interface "class SampleData:INotifyPropertyChanged" helps in free some bytes but other objects are still referencing SampleData. I have used MVVM Light Toolkit in my project. Class `ObservableObject` of this lib takes care of all this.

Comment: @ChrisF please help me... i need your guidance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646450/xamarin-form-carouselview-out-of-memory-exception/40648890#40648890  follow my answer to design your listview.

Comment: @MikeMa Thanks, but why should i cache my ListView Items as i want to show all of them. Also When I'm updating the ItemsSource every time i update the List.

Comment: @anubhav If you want to show many items in your ListView you need cache these items. Because your memory is not enough to show all of the items. If your item is not a lot you do not need to do that. You update the list, because if you store all of your items in your List your memory still not enough, you need keep the size of the list.